# PCRE regex to match next occurrence of specific pattern or EOF

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, pcre

I have a file with following content:

```
#### v2

START MATCH

Text explaning things and stuff.
This has to be matched.

END MATCH

#### v1

Do not match this part (or anything
below "END MATCH" part).

#### v0

Do not match this either.
```

I'm trying to match everything between `START MATCH` and `END MATCH` (including new lines). However, the text below `END MATCH` might not exist, instead it can be the end of file. Also, there is no literal `END MATCH` text, it's just a marker to show what I'm trying to achieve.

I was trying out the following regex pattern `(?<=# v.\n\n)(.|\n)*(?=\n(?:#.*?|$))` which seems to me fine if the file ends with `END MATCH`, but if there are additional lines below it (starting with new line and `#` character), my pattern captures that part as well.

How can I modify my pattern (probably just the last part `(?=\n(?:#.*?|$))`?) to exclude everything after `END MATCH`?

Example can be tested here: https://regex101.com/r/bJAZZq/1

Comment: It's called whitespace trim `(?s)\#+\s+v2.*?(?=\s*(?:\#+|$))`

https://regex101.com/r/VUjL5t/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#\h+v\d+\R{2}\K(?s:.*?)(?=\R#|\z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K4TzWz/2).

**Details**

- `#` - a `#` char
- `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `v` - a `v` letter
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\R{2}` - two line break sequences
- `\K` - omit the text matched so far
- `(?s:.*?)` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?=\R#|\z)` - up to the first occurrence of a line break sequence and then `#` or end of string.

Please note that `(.|\n)*` is a very bad regex construct consuming a lot of computational resources and leading to performance issues, you should never use it.

`\R` construct is very useful in PCRE and similar regex engines, it matches any kind of line breaks, `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n` and even more sometimes depending on the options or exact library implementation.

`\K` allows to use `+` and `*` quantifiers before the text you want to actually grab with the regex, unlike the lookbehinds, where the pattern length must be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation as well as a warning about usage of `(.|\n)*` part!

Answer (score 0):

Use non-greedy matching `*?`:

```
(?<=# v.\n\n)(.|\n)*?(?=\n(?:#.*?|$))
```

Googled this for you: [Regular Expression Tutorial Part 5: Greedy and Non-Greedy Quantification](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2786107/regular-expression-tutorial-part-5--greedy-and-non-greedy-quantification.html)